# elasticsearch update api - script do not change indexed document

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to use update api in elasticsearch 1.3.5. I have following document I am trying to update:

```
{
  "_index": "geocode",
  "_type": "google",
  "_id": "kolb dfsafa 303 46546456 z ",
  "_version": 8,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "results": [
      {"formatted_address": "kolb 303, 46546456 dfsafa-dfsafa-d",
        "geometry": {
          "location": {
            "lat": 35.0360533,
            "lng": 14.5632209
          },
          "location_type": "ROOFTOP"
        },
        "types": [
          "street_address"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
  }
}
```

I have following script:

```
POST  /geocode/google/kolb%20dfsafa%20303%2046546456%20z%20/_update
{
    "script":"ctx._source.results.geometry.location.lat==latitude",
    "lang": "groovy",
    "params":{
        "latitude" : 0.0
    }
}
```

Where I would like to update lat position to 0.0. Api call finishes successfully(version increassed etc.) however nothing is updated.

```
{
   "_index": "geocode",
   "_type": "google",
   "_id": "kolb dfsafa 303 46546456 z ",
   "_version": 9
}
```

Any hint where to look?

Comment: Dude , change == to =. Script should be "ctx._source.results.geometry.location.lat=latitude"

Comment: @vineeth Dude,  I tried that neither assignment nor addition +=  didn't work so that was the reason to post it on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As results is array , you need to address it as an array. Remember , you are working on the orginal _source and not the data from field data cache. Which means you need to use the right JSON path.

```
POST  /geocode/google/kolb%20dfsafa%20303%2046546456%20z%20/_update
{
    "script":"ctx._source.results[0].geometry.location.lat=latitude",
    "lang": "groovy",
    "params":{
        "latitude" : 0.0
    }
}
```

You can refer to this [link](http://blog.qbox.io/introduction-to-elasticsearch-scripting) on more information of this use case and more examples on Update API

Comment: Thx. Just instead == need a put assignment =

Comment: Is it possible to use * to apply it to all elements of the array? It is valid JSON path but getting GroovyScriptExecutionException[IllegalArgumentException[argument type mismatch]]

Comment: You will need to loop tru all elements , * is not supported